# unable to access an object created using require.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, require

**Hello everyone,**

I have just recently started learning the **require.js** , but I don't seem to understand as how does the whole mechanism work...and especialy how do I access the variables/objects created using this javascript library.

Let me explain it further in the example below..

**webroot/page.jsp**

```
<html>
<script data-main="js/page" src="js/lib/require.js"></script>
</html>
```

**webroot/js/common.js**

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'js/lib',
    paths: {
        app: '../app',
    }
});
```

**webroot/js/app/page.js**

```
require(['./common'], function (common) {
    require(['./app/page/init'], function(page)
    {
        page.load(1);
    });
});
```

**webroot/js/app/page/init.js**

```
define(['./load'], function (load) {
    var LoadPage = new load();
    return LoadPage;
});
```

**webroot/js/app/page/load.js**

```
define(function () {
    function loadPage() {
    }

    loadPage.prototype = {
        load: function (page_id) {
            console.log("Opening page "+page_id+" ");
        }
    };

    return loadPage;
});
```

now when I run the page everything works perfectly, but now I'd like to execute the load method by clicking on a button.

```
<div onclick="page.load(2);"> </div>
```

but this does not work..So I'd like to know if there is any possibility to bind this action to any button or link...whatever..

(apologies for my bad english)

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about as below assuming you are using JQuery:

```
<div id="divPageLoad"></div>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $("#divPageLoad").on("click", function() {
       page.load(2);
   });

</script>
```

Comment: I think you're right, this may be the only way I can bind that  function to a button.